# Find the max value of subset of a list?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, tuples, subset

I have a Python data parsing script that collects data into a list of tuples.  The first element of the tuple is an 'index' to reference a set of related data.  I want to find the maximum value for a second element in the tuple for each data set 'index'.

The data looks like this:

```
[[1, 99, '43.12', '-76,21'], [1, 98, ''43.13', '-76.22'], etc. ]
```

The first element in the tuple is the 'index' value.  So later on it increments.

```
[2, 52, '42.99', '-75.95']
```

So I want to find the maximum value for the second element within each 'index' value. I would like to pull out that value on-demand, rather than creating a list of results, i.e. find me the max value of element 2 for data set 8.

I've searched around quite a bit to find an answer, but none seemed close enough. Most of the questions I've found don't show how to explicitly select an element value, and most create a list of results.

Comment: I think by 'tuple' you mean 'list'; at least, that is what is generated if you use brackets to create the object.

Comment: `max` has an optional parameter `key`

Comment: Also, if the first number is an 'index', why in your data set are there two lists with an index of 1?

Comment: Please provide [mcve]

Comment: Welcome to [SO]! As you may know, Stack Overflow is a question-and-answer site. Readers, such as yourself, ask questions and other readers try to answer them. Your post is missing the essential element of a quality [so] post: **a question!**  What, precisely, is your question?

Comment: You don't appear to have tried solving this, what code have you written to address your own problem? Can you share it?

Comment: @GregSchmit - The 'index' sets apart a group of related data.  So group 1 may contain hundreds of entries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function might return the value you want:

```
def my_max(data, index):
    return max(datum[1] for datum in data if datum[0] == index)
```

Demonstration:

```
def my_max(data, index):
    return max(datum[1] for datum in data if datum[0] == index)

my_list = [
    [1, 99, '43.12', '-76,21'],
    [1, 98, '43.13', '-76.22'],
    [2, 52, '42.99', '-75.95'],
]

assert my_max(my_list, 1) == 99
assert my_max(my_list, 2) == 52
```

Comment: Ahh!  I think this is what I'm looking for!  I'll give it a try!

Comment: It worked like a charm!  I upvoted, but it doesn't show due to my current rep.  (Just started on stackoverflow.)  Thanks for the help!